# Nowhere differentiability of Weierstrass function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, examples-counterexamples, trigonometric-series

It's again from Tao's book.

Let  $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function
$$f:= \sum_{n=1}^\infty 4^{-n} \sin(8^n\pi x)$$
Show that for every 8-dyadic interval $[\frac{j}{8^k},\frac{j+1}{8^k}]$ with $k\geq 1$, one has $|f(\frac{j+1}{8^k})-f(\frac{j}{8^k})| \geq C4^{-k}$ for some absolute constant $C > 0$.For $n>k, |f(\frac{j+1}{8^k})-f(\frac{j}{8^k})|=0$. But how to get the inequality when $n<k$?

Answer (score 2):

#### Disclaimer

This is a proof for the version of $f$  with $\sin$ replaced by $\cos$. The estimates get  more awkward if sines are used, without any added insight.

Let $f_n(x) = 4^{-n} \cos (8^n \pi x)$. Observe the following:

1. $f_n((j+1)/8^k) = f_n(j/8^k)$ for $n > k$.
2. Since $\cos \pi m = (-1)^m$, it follows that
   $$|f_n((j+1)/8^k) - f_n(j/8^k)|=2\cdot 4^{-k},\quad n=k$$
3. Cosine function has Lipschitz constant $1$, hence 
   $$|f_n((j+1)/8^k) - f_n(j/8^k)|\le  4^{-n}8^{n-k}\pi  ,\quad n<k$$

Finally, use the reverse triangle inequality: 
$$ \begin{split}
&|f ((j+1)/8^k) - f  (j/8^k)| \\ & \ge 
|f_k ((j+1)/8^k) - f_k  (j/8^k)| - \sum_{n=1}^{k-1} |f_n ((j+1)/8^k) - f_n  (j/8^k)| \\ &\ge 
2\cdot 4^{-k} - \pi 4^{-k}\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}   4^{n-k} \ge 4^{-k}(2 - \pi/3) \end{split}$$ 
which is the desired estimate.

Comment: Is your observation 1 wrong? I think it still equals 0. Moreover the application of the reverse triangle inequality seems a little obscure to me as well..Don't we need to sum up the difference of the $n-k$ sine functions? Thank you very much for your clarification! @Weapon of Choice

Comment: I imagined things that ought to have been there... See the revised version.

Comment: In the last sum there should be $2^{n-k}$ istead of $4^{n-k}$ which gives estimate $\geq 4^{-k} (2 - \pi)$ and does not solve the problem.